# Deserialize ExternalIDs in Google apps Directory API

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client, google-directory-api

I can see the JSON response but I'm not able to deserialize the ExternalIDs in google apps directory API. (C#)

```
var users = service.Users.Get(EMail).Execute();
var externalIDs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserExternalId>(users.ExternalIds);
```

Gives a compiler error:

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string, params Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: What is the content of users.EternalIds?

Comment: It's a JSON array of Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.UserExternalId

Comment: I was able to get it to work by using dynamic but I'd like to strong type the class.  It appears that the class variables may not have the same case as the XML... eg. CustomType vs customType

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason is an error in your code. As you commented the object ExternalIds contains a json array. Thus your code should be:

```
UserExternalId[] exId = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserExternalId[]>(x.ExternalIds.ToString());
```

Notice the **[]** on the objecttype to deserialize.